# root filesystem too small - what's preferrable?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, lvm

After a number of upgrades, and a steady flow of software installed, the original root filesystem is starting to split at the seams.
The original (Notebook) setup:

```
 (LVM) /        17G   everything but "payload" data
 sda1  /boot   228M   
 (LVM) swap      8G   
 (LVM) /home    xxG   home directories
 (LVM) /export xxxG   Collections that should not clog up home directories, have a
                      larger backup cycle, and can be restored from external sources.
                      Examples. src, install, iso-images, Video, ...
```

Originally, the lvm setup had a sound reserve to grow existing filesystems as needed, but that space has been spent, so some stuff that never ever got used got relocated to the background server.

### Options to handle the squeze:

- grow the root filesystem at the expense of /export
- split the root filesystem

  - /var contains a growing set of archived packages in /var/cache/apt/archives
  - /usr is another large subset to split out - grows with every package installed

Answer (score 1):

17 Gb should be more then enough for /

Clean your archives. `sudo apt-get clean all` There is no need to keep all those outdated .deb

If you still have a problem with / , clean out you old logs.

If you still have a problem with the small size of your root partition, then yes you have to add space. You can downsize an existing LV or add additional PV. There is no single method or best practice.

The only potential problem with LVM is that it can be difficult to downsize an existing LV.

Your problem is going to be with such a small /boot partition, you will have to constantly remove old kernels. If 17 Gb

Comment: 17 GiB should be more than enough _only_ if your `/var` is on a different filesystem that `/`.  See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#How_big_should_my_partitions_be.3F)

Comment: Once I had considered 15 G sufficient for /. Then I grew it to 17. A clean-all was done before the upgrade to 14.04, so the current squeeze shows the swing that's needed for a system upgrade. Logfiles are rotated and monitored for excessive growth.

Comment: You are right saying that the /boot is terribly small - it used to be enough, but that is no longer true. Unfortunately my options for resizing that partition are limited. Any ideas that don't involve wrecking the Physical Volume residing on the remaining cylinders?

Comment: Well, I can only give general advice. LVM is very much designed, IMO, to add a PV when your run out of space. I think it is perhaps easiest to add a PV, it would solve your problems. If that is not an option, you evaluate your LV. / need an additional X Gb (20 ?) and /home has Y available and /export has Z. so downsize your LV, add the free space to /boot and / . Downsizing a LV can be challenging as the data can be fragmented across the physcial space and there is not easy way to defragment. You back up , delete data, resize, and restore.

Answer (score 0):

### Tradidional reasons for splitting:

A `root` filesystem filled to the brink can be a very ungraceful beast to handle. Thus the need to split out fast-growing filesystems such as `/var` (After all, all those logfiles, caches, spoolfiles historycally were aggregated at `/var` to make this scenario possible)

The separation of `/usr` sort of predates package systems - it used to be an attempt to keep a read-only collection of software with special regard to diskless (or reduced-disk) clients.

The goal of that split was to keep system configuration and an emergency roadset for system maintenance on a per-system root filesystem, and share the large chunk of software needed or desired by the user(s) without replicating.

A separate `/var` ideally allowed the root filesystem to be on partition mounted read-only, a concept that still would seem desirable for the use of media with limited
write-cycles.

So for the moment, it does seem desirable to keep `/var` separate, but there doesn't seem to be a real benefit to keeping `/usr` on a partition of its own - it might be more economical to assign that space to the `root` filesystem directly, saving the overhead for a separate partition.